# How can I make zshell skip confirming substitutions?

Tags: bash, zsh

If I run the following commands in bash:

```
mkdir foo
cd !$
```

The second command will be interpreted as `cd foo` and executed.

In zshell (at least with my current configuration), it will make the substitution, create the command `cd foo`, and leave my cursor at the end of it, so that I have to hit enter again to execute.

Is there a way to make it just execute the command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `man zshoptions`:

> HIST_VERIFY
>
> Whenever the user enters a line with history expansion, 
>   don't execute the line directly; instead, perform history expansion and reload the line into the editing buffer.

So just add `setopt no_hist_verify`to your .zshrc

**Edit:** Remove accidental single quote that was breaking command

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just a small correction: I had to use `setopt no_histverify` (without the second underscore) for it to work. This is with zsh 5.0.2.